# E/System: Ignoring attempt to set property "file.encoding" to value "ISO-8859-1"

Tags: java, android, iso-8859-1

When i try to this in Android Studio it ignores the encoding resulting a disaster in my program.But it does not have any problem when i try this on java.

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding","ISO-8859-1");
            Field charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
            charset.setAccessible(true);
            charset.set(null,null);
```

on the log it displays:

> E/System: Ignoring attempt to set property "file.encoding" to value "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: This looks like an Android error message - what has this to do with the character encoding set in Android Studio? Do you mean you set the file encoding in your Android App?

Comment: i was trying to set file.encoding to ISO-8859-1 in my app where i was trying to open a audio file,but android revokes it and shows that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a system property can be prevented by a SecurityManager if one is installed. An Android application can be expected to run in a sandbox which means that there is a SecurityManager in place that resticts the system properties you can set (there might be some but don't count on it).

A regular Java application in general runs without a SecurityManager so setting this property works.

Normally setting the file.encoding during runtime isn't necessary. If your application breaks without a specific value for `file.encoding` you most likely do something wrong within your code, e.g. creating a `String` froma `byte[]` without specifying the charset to be used or vice versa.

In short: In order to get your application to work you need to change your application from e.g.

```
byte[] myBytes = myString.getBytes();
String mynewString = new String(myBytes);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
```

to

```
byte[] myBytes = myString.getBytes("8859_1");
String mynewString = new String(myBytes, "8859_1");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "8859_1");
```

Oh and something more:

```
Field charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
charset.setAccessible(true);
charset.set(null,null);
```

This is quite a hack and you should feel dirty for that ;-) This won't solve all problem, e.g. when you do HTTP-requests, `file.encoding` is used as well to decide what charset should be used to encode HTTP-request-header-values. The charset value for that is kept in a different member of a different class, same for similar functionalities in JavaMail, etc. Changing the charset-values in members of "internal" classes is quite likely breaking things, so don't do that and as I already wrote, it should be completely unnecessary.

Comment: the main problem is i am reading a file and when i am building the string it reads as utf-8 can you suggest something that would read the string in iso-8859 format.........?

Comment: @SharanyoChatterjee Look at my examples: `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "8859_1");` allows you to read in text from a file using ISO-8859-1 as charset. Alternatively read in the data as byte-array and use `new String(myBytes, "8859_1");` to create a `String` from it with ISO-8859-1 as charset.

Comment: your example very good and descriptive thanks for that.my problem is when i'm using reader.Read() the integer i read is perfect,but when i typecast it to char some times it is returning wrong character,is it because mp3 files are on some other encoding than 8859 or something else? i am really confused here.

Comment: @SharanyoChatterjee MP3 is binary and shouldn't be read with a `Reader` but with an `InputStream`.

Comment: the problem is the code i'm writing requires printWriter so i must write in a string

Comment: @SharanyoChatterjee Using `8859_1` as charset should lead to a "1:1"-mapping from binary to character and vice versa. It seems that your way of converting data is buggy, but for that you need to provide the corresponding code and is most likely a new question, because this one I personally see as answered. But the requirement for a PrintWriter to send binary data sounds really strange, there should be a different way to do this but again, without the actual code it's impossible to say anything more specific.